# How to solve the differential equation with delta function on right hand side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I have a differential equation of the form below. How to solve this. It is actually a fourth order beam equation with a derivative of the delta function. I have solved for just delta function in the right-hand side. But I never solved the derivative of the delta function on the right-hand side of the equation.

\begin{align}
   \begin{split}
      \frac{\mathrm{d}^4\psi(\eta)}{\mathrm{d}\eta^4}-\beta^4\psi(\eta)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} K_{r,j}\psi'(\eta)\,\delta'(\eta-\zeta_{3,j}) \label{eq:Governin equation in w}
   \end{split}
   \end{align}

Comment: Do you have any initial conditions? You could just take the Laplace transform.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch:** For convenient, let us take $\beta = K_{r, j} = 1$. Then you have
\begin{align}
\psi^{(4)}(t) - \psi(t) = \sum^n_{j=1}\psi'(t)\delta(t-\zeta_j).
\end{align}
Using the fact that
\begin{align}
\psi'(t)\delta(t-\zeta_j) = -\psi''(\zeta_j)\delta(t-\zeta_j) + \psi'(\zeta_j) \delta'(t-\zeta_j)
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
\psi^{(4)}(t) - \psi(t) = \sum^n_{j=1} \left\{-\psi''(\zeta_j)\delta(t-\zeta_j) + \psi'(\zeta_j) \delta'(t-\zeta_j)\right\}.
\end{align}
Now take the Laplace tranform and solve for $\mathcal{L}[\psi](s)$. Finally, apply the inverse transform to recover $\psi$.